# Changing BUNIT in csh for a FITS file

Tags: linux, csh, astronomy, fits

I'm writing code in .csh, and I'm trying to change the bunit header for a [FITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) file from K (kelvin) to km/s. How can I do that?

I know in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) I would use new_fitsfile.header['BUNIT']='km/s', but that won't work in the current .csh code, and it's not an option to switch it to Python code.

Comment: What do you mean by "a code in .csh"? csh is a shell and has no specific provisions for working with FITS files.

Answer (score 0):

If this is needed only once, call interactively fv or ds9, move to the header, edit the header card and save the result.

For generic batch jobs, one needs some online FITS editor like fmodhead [fmodhead](http://sci.astro.fits.narkive.com/58onm2uX/hierarch-keywords-with-fmodhead-of-heatools), fthedit, or my [fedithead](http://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~mathar/progs/fedithead.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s:BUNIT   = 'K       ':BUNIT   = 'km/s    ':g" old.fits >new.fits
```

and be **very** careful to count the significant spaces.